# Outlook Add-in LaunchEvents from a mailto email

Tags: outlook-web-addins, mailto, outlook-web-app

I have an outlook add-in that has a "OnNewMessageCompose" handler that is being executed fine when clicking "New" or "Reply". My issue is when I click on a mailto: link. The new email window pops up but the add-in doesn't fire. I also have the "OnMessageRecipientsChanged" handler implemeted with the same results.
I found this link ([Outlook plugin not loading after clicking mailto links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265364/outlook-plugin-not-loading-after-clicking-mailto-links)) but it is from 14 years ago and I am hoping that the feature has been implemented.
The email pops up but no events are triggered

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">
    <LaunchEvents>
        <LaunchEvent Type="OnNewMessageCompose" FunctionName="onNewMessageComposeHandler"/>
        <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageCompose" FunctionName="onMessageComposeHandler" />
        <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageRecipientsChanged" FunctionName="onMessageRecipientsChanged"/>
    </LaunchEvents>
    <!-- Identifies the runtime to be used (also referenced by the Runtime element). -->
    <SourceLocation resid="WebViewRuntime.Url"/>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

here is the code I expect to be run. just the body to be set to some test text

```
 Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync("does this get set", { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html }, function (asyncResult) {
     if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {
         console.log("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
     }
 });
```

any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!
Thank you

when clicking a "mailto" I expect the body to have some text set